# Intergral involving arcus sinus and square root

Tags: integration, analysis

While computing certain triple integral, I met the following one which I was unable to compute. I would be greatful for any suggestions:
$$\int x\arcsin{\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x}} \,dx$$

Comment: i would say by parts the result looks ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integration by parts with $u=\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x}$ and $dv = x\,dx$. This gets rid of the transcendental function. The resulting integral is not pretty, but it's tractable.